# Does conditioning preserve equality in distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be random variables all defined on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$. Suppose that $X \stackrel{d}{=}Y.$ What conditions (if any) are sufficient to say that $(X|Z) \stackrel{d}{=} (Y|Z)$?

Comment: That $(X,Z)\stackrel d=(Y,Z)$. Otherwise, take $(X,Y)$ uniform on $\{-1,1\}^2$ and $Z=X$.

Comment: @Did apologies if this is obvious, but why is $(X,Z)\stackrel d=(Y,Z)$ sufficient?

Comment: Because the conditional distribution of $X$ conditionally on $Z$ depends only on the distribution of $(X,Z)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $X = Y$ in distribution corresponds to $P(X \leq x) = P(Y\leq x)$ for a particular $x$ in the state space, then you're asking for conditions such that 
$$ P( X \leq x \big| Z = z ) = P(Y \leq x \big| Z= z) ?$$

If this is the case, then, a quick condition that would guarantee this is independence of $X,Y,Z$. For then,
$$  P( X \leq x \big| Z = z ) = \frac{P(X\leq x )P(Z =z)}{P(Z=z)} = P(X\leq x) = P(Y \leq x) = \frac{P(Y\leq x)P(Z=z)}{P(Z=z)} =P(Y\leq x\big|Z=z) .$$

I worry that this is more simplistic than what you're looking for?

Comment: yes, my fault. I should have specified that the random variables are dependent. Nevertheless that is a perfect answer to my question.

Comment: Please avoid `\big|` (`\mid` being an alternative).